# Twig pre-compilation seems to be skipping templates

Tags: php, twig

I wrote this script for pre-compiling my Twig templates:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../www/autoload.php';


$twig = \WebEngineX\ServiceLocator::twig();
$twig->enableAutoReload();
$templateDir = dirname(__DIR__).'/twig';
$cacheDir = $twig->getCache();


$iter = new RegexIterator(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($templateDir)),'~\.twig$~');
/** @var \SplFileInfo[] $files */
$files = iterator_to_array($iter);
$errors = [];

echo "Compiling Twig templates\n";
$pb = new WxProgressBar(count($files));

$exitCode = 0;

foreach($files as $path) {
    $relPath = WXU::relative_path($templateDir, $path->getPathname());
    try {
        $twig->loadTemplate($relPath);
    } catch(Twig_Error_Syntax $err) {
        $errors[$relPath] = $err->getMessage();
    }
    $pb->increment();
}
$pb->complete();

if($errors) {
    fwrite(STDERR, "Error(s) found:\n");
    foreach($errors as $filename => $err) {
        echo "- $filename: $err\n";
    }
}

exit($errors ? 1 : 0);
```

I run this before deployment to

1. speed up the first page request (user doesn't have to wait for compilation)
2. flush any old templates (I have `auto_reload` set to false in production)
3. catch any syntax errors at compile time (this script fails if there's an error)

The problem I'm having is that even though I've compiled all my `.twig` files, when I click around my web app, it's still compiling things, which means not everything was compiled.

I ran a diff on one of my pre-compiled templates vs one of the run-time compiled templates and the differences look like this:

Pre-compiled:

```
echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, $this->getAttribute((isset($context["client"]) ? $context["client"] : null), "name", array()), "html", null, true);
```

Run-compiled:

```
echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, $this->getAttribute((isset($context["client"]) ? $context["client"] : $this->getContext($context, "client")), "name", array()), "html", null, true);
```

Why isn't the pre-compile adding `$this->getContext($context, "client")`?

Comment: It might have something to do with different environments/settings.